# SQL Server restoring to a different destination puts source DB into restoring state

Tags: sql-server, database-restore

I'm using a backup file to restore a database to a different database. The source database is the only one in the backup file and is selected as source.
A different database is the destination.

The restore option is overwrite the existing database (with replace). The restore as files are renamed to the destination database's files.

Other than the selected database's name in the file, the source is not involved at all in the restore.

After the restore the source database immediately goes into recovery and I have to restore it to get it out.

Even though it is not being touched.

Can anyone tell me how to stop this?

The server and studio versions are below.

Very much appreciated.

- SQL Server 2008 (Version 10.0.2757.0)
- SQL Server Management Studio 2012 (Version 11.0.6020.0)

(I have searched for this issue but found nothing fitting this description.)

Comment: Are you able to restore your backup as a new database?  What version of SQL Server are you running?

Comment: "the source database immediately goes into recovery" wut? a restore is never connected to 'the source DB', it comes from a file. I think you are overriding the actual files of the original database, effectively corrupting it. Is the source a 'device'? hard to know unless we see what you actually doing.

Comment: "The restore as files are renamed to the destination database's files." The target DB is properly restored.  Restoring to a new database does the same thing, the source DB goes into restoring mode.

Comment: I finally Found it!  There is an option now in the restore wizard to create a Tail log AND keep the target DB in recovery, and it is all CHECKED BY DEFAULT! Thanks everyone for the tips, much appreciated.